# multiprocess rabbit consumer

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, rabbitmq, python-multiprocessing, pika

Thanks in advance.
I'm new in Multiprocessing.
I've created a process through which i want to consume the data trough Rabbit MQueue at same time but it runs one process at a time.

```
def start_consum(queue_name):
    channel.basic_consume(func, queue=queue_name)
    channel.start_consuming()

def process_start(number):
    from multiprocessing import Process
    events = ["ev1","ev2","ev3"]
    for process in range(number):
        for event in events:
            proc = Process(target= start_consum(event))
            proc.daemon = True
            proc.start()


process_start(10)
```

In above code it start consuming the first event and then it starts the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a thread for this.

```
class Threaded_worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('', '')
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(credentials=self.credentials,host=))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        events = ["ev1","ev2","ev3"]
        for event in events:
            self.channel.basic_consume(func, queue=event)             

    def run(self):
        print 'start consuming'
        self.channel.start_consuming()

    def thread_start(numberofthreads):                
        for _ in range(numberofthreads):
            td = Threaded_worker()
            td.setDaemon(True)
            td.start()
```